# JQuery Function doesn't work while the ticker Updating the panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

Why the JQuery function doesn't work while the ticker Updating the panel? Please see the code below.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Schedule_Timer" runat="server" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Schedule_UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Schedule_Timer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Schedule_Panel" runat="server" Height="250px"  Width="250px">
            <asp:Literal ID="Schedule_Label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script>
    $('#test').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollUp',
        timeout: 6000,
        delay: -2000
    });
</script>
```

The `Schedule_Label` is filled in via code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Schedule_Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Schedule_Timer.Tick
    PrintTheSchedule()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintTheSchedule()
    //This is just for example, the actual data is taken from gridview based on the realtime
    Schedule_Label.Text = "<div id='test'>" & _
                "<div>test 1</div>" & _
                "<div>test 2</div>" & _
                "<div>test 3</div>" & _
                "<div>"        
End Sub
```

For the first 10 seconds, the JQuery do cycling the `test` div. But after the UpdatePanel refreshed, then the JQuery doesn't running anymore and it caused all of the `test` div value showed up on the page. How to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a preety simple answer.

The jquery function executed on the page load itself only. So when the Timer tick the jquery function does not remain valid again.

So what you need to do is:

In the PrintTheSchedule function call the javascript function again like

IN C# i do this like

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "runScript", "RunScriptAgain();", true);
```

And in the Aspx Page do

```
<script>

 function RunScriptAgain() 
 {
  $('#test').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollUp',
    timeout: 6000,
    delay: -2000
   });
 }
```

//  Required for the first time

```
$(document).ready(function() {  RunScriptAgain(); })
```

Comment: Hi, it works. But why the first 10 seconds the JQuery doesn't running? And after 10 seconds, the code works for me..

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 In the page load also you run the ScriptManager code. Becuase the RunScript function need to be run during the first time or load this function using Jquery Document ready

Answer (score 0):

after the update panel is refreshed.. then old div with id test is destroyed and therefore you will have to bind the cycle function on every panel update.
one other way of doing this is to use jquerys livequery plugin
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery
and modify the script as follows

```
$('#test').livequery(function(){
$(this).cycle({
        fx: 'scrollUp',
        timeout: 6000,
        delay: -2000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

probably, you need to re-initialize cycle bec. the contents would change